# Groovy different results on using equals() and == on a GStringImpl

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading, equals, gstring

According to the [Groovy docs](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_equals_and_code_code), the `==` is just a "clever" `equals()` as it also takes care of avoiding `NullPointerException`:

> Java’s `==` is actually Groovy’s `is()` method, and Groovy’s `==` is a clever `equals()`!
>
> [...]
>
> But to do the usual `equals()` comparison, you should prefer Groovy’s `==`, as it also takes care of avoiding `NullPointerException`, independently of whether the left or right is `null` or not.

So, the `==` and `equals()` should return the same value if the objects are not null. However, I'm getting unexpected results on executing the following script:

```groovy
println "${'test'}" == 'test'
println "${'test'}".equals('test')
```

The output that I'm getting is:

```
true
false
```

Is this a known bug related to `GStringImpl` or something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Nice question, the surprising thing about the code above is that

```
println "${'test'}".equals('test')
```

returns `false`. The other line of code returns the expected result, so let's forget about that.

### Summary

```
"${'test'}".equals('test')
```

The object that `equals` is called on is of type `GStringImpl` whereas `'test'` is of type `String`, so they are not considered equal.

### But Why?

Obviously the `GStringImpl` implementation of `equals` could have been written such that when it is passed a `String` that contain the same characters as `this`, it returns true. Prima facie, this seems like a reasonable thing to do.

I'm guessing that the reason it wasn't written this way is because it would violate the `equals` contract, which states that:

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

The implementation of `String.equals(Object other)` will always return false when passed a `GSStringImpl`, so if `GStringImpl.equals(Object other)` returns true when passed any `String`, it would be in violation of the symmetric requirement.

Comment: An important note: the implementation of Collection.contains and the "in" operator will use the equals method and not the compareTo. This can get hard to spot when it is buried underneath a few layers `['test'].contains("${'test'}") ==> false`

Answer (score 60):

In groovy `a == b` checks first for a `compareTo` method and uses `a.compareTo(b) == 0` if a `compareTo` method exists. Otherwise it will use `equals`.

Since Strings and GStrings implement `Comparable` there is a `compareTo` method available.

The following prints true, as expected:

```
println "${'test'}".compareTo('test') == 0
```

The behaviour of `==` is documented in the [Groovy Language Documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_behaviour_of_code_code):

> In Java `==` means equality of primitive types or identity for objects. In Groovy `==` means equality in all cases. It translates to `a.compareTo(b) == 0`, when evaluating equality for `Comparable` objects, and `a.equals(b)` otherwise. To check for identity (reference equality), use the `is` method: `a.is(b)`. From Groovy 3, you can also use the `===` operator (or negated version): `a === b` (or `c !== d`).

The full list of operators are provided in the Groovy Language Documentation for [operator overloading](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#Operator-Overloading):

| Operator | Method |
| --- | --- |
| `+` | a.plus(b) |
| `-` | a.minus(b) |
| `*` | a.multiply(b) |
| `/` | a.div(b) |
| `%` | a.mod(b) |
| `**` | a.power(b) |
| `|` | a.or(b) |
| `&` | a.and(b) |
| `^` | a.xor(b) |
| `as` | a.asType(b) |
| `a()` | a.call() |
| `a[b]` | a.getAt(b) |
| `a[b] = c` | a.putAt(b, c) |
| `a in b` | b.isCase(a) |
| `<<` | a.leftShift(b) |
| `>>` | a.rightShift(b) |
| `>>>` | a.rightShiftUnsigned(b) |
| `++` | a.next() |
| `--` | a.previous() |
| `+a` | a.positive() |
| `-a` | a.negative() |
| `~a` | a.bitwiseNegate() |

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful indeed! One thing that I noticed was that == uses equals or compareTo, however != uses equals only. Isn't it a bit counterintuitive?

Comment: Definitely. I've also added, an additional bit about `==` not being symmetric in groovy.

Comment: Made a mistake. == is symmetric in groovy.

Comment: While that table is super handy, it's a bit misleading as == isn't actually on it.

Comment: Linked to relevant part of the documentation now.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here as an additional answer, so it can be found easily for Groovy beginners.
I am explicitly transforming the GString to a normal String before comparing it.

```
println "${'test'}".equals("test");
println "${'test'}".toString().equals("test");
```

results in

```
false
true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).