# Groovy Comparing two Strings

Tags: groovy

Why these two strings are not matching on neither one: .equals() OR  .compareTo() OR == OR Objects.equals()? I believe it should match atleast at one comparions.

```
 Process proc1 = 'cat /home/output.txt'.execute()
 Process proc2 = 'grep -o -m 1 webServiceReturn'.execute()

 Process all = proc1 | proc2

   def log =  all.text.toString()
   String svc = "webServiceReturn";

   println (log)
   println (svc)

      //if (svc.equals(log)) {
      //if (svc.compareTo(log)) {
      //if(svc == log) {
      if (Objects.equals((svc),(log))) {
               println "MATCHED" }
      else {
               println "NOT MATCHED" }
```

The result on all four comparison are:

```
webServiceReturn
webServiceReturn
NOT MATCHED
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that one of these has extra whitespace?

Comment: try "assert svc == log" . you will see a log which compare the two strings characters by characters

Comment: @JérémieB. Yes it worked with: 
if ("assert svc == log") {

Comment: it's not what i proposed. assert can be used to format an error, and help to see the difference. it's not means to be used in a real comparaison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and making one minor modification to trim the white space on the results allowed it to match.

Do a trim on your all.text to remove any extraneous white space.

```
def log =  all.text.trim()
```

You don't need the .toString() call either.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned from another StackOverflow answer that using `equals()`, `.contains` and `in` fail to see same contents of strings of different type.

[Groovy different results on using equals() and == on a GStringImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682206/groovy-different-results-on-using-equals-and-on-a-gstringimpl)

According to an answer by @dunes in the above question, the Groovy comparison using `==` uses `compareTo()` opportunistically before `equals()`. (The `==` comparison in Groovy has a remarkable difference from Java where it compares references).

```java
def expandedString = "${'test'}"
def simpleString = 'test'
println "Expansion: ${expandedString}"
println "equals 'test' ? ${expandedString.equals(simpleString)}"
println "    == 'test' ? ${expandedString == simpleString}"
```

The above outputs the following,

```
Expansion: test
equals 'test' ? false
    == 'test' ? true
```

The following excerpt from the Groovy documentation omits the `compareTo()` piece that makes `==` different from `equals()`.

> In Groovy, using `==` to test equality is different from using the same operator in Java. In Groovy, it is calling equals. If you want to compare reference equality, you should use `is` like in the following example:
>
> > def list1 = ['Groovy 1.8','Groovy 2.0','Groovy 2.3']
> >
> > def list2 = ['Groovy 1.8','Groovy 2.0','Groovy 2.3']
> >
> > assert list1 == list2
> >
> > assert !list1.is(list2)

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_identity_operator