# Not able to compare string entered from Input Dialog with a different string in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, compare, gstring

Below is my code:

```
def readln = javax.swing.JOptionsPane.&showInputDialog
def env = readln 'Which environment you want to test'
```

I entered input as `syst`

While i am comparing this is what i am doing

```
if("$env".equalsIgnoreCase("syst")){
some code
}
```

also tried many other ways to compare like

```
if($env.equalsIgnoreCase("syst"))
if(env.equalsUIgnoreCase("syst"))
if("${'env'}".equalsIgnoreCase("syst"))
```

but none of the above working , the condition is not satisfied. How to compare the string declared with a string entered from dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

first - the classname `JOptionsPane` is wrong (it's `JOptionPane` - without the `s`)

below is the working code.

you can run it from groovy console.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane

def readln = JOptionPane.&showInputDialog
def env = readln 'Which environment you want to test'
if(env=='syst'){
    println "EQUALS"
}
if('syst'.equalsIgnoreCase(env)){
    println "EQUALS equalsIgnoreCase 1"
}
if(env.equalsIgnoreCase('syst')){
    println "EQUALS equalsIgnoreCase 2"
}
if("${env}".equalsIgnoreCase('syst')){
    println "EQUALS equalsIgnoreCase 3"
}
```

all 4 comparisons works fine.

however `'syst'.equalsIgnoreCase(env)` is preferable if you'd like to compare ignoring case.

because the `env` could be null at this point

Answer (score 0):

try expand it directly to a string as - "${env}"

Comment: not "equals", in groovy this is very badly implemented and will return false in between String and GString, try to use ==

Comment: you can refer to this topic in that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682206/groovy-different-results-on-using-equals-and-on-a-gstringimpl

Comment: i am not sure why but still this is not working `if("${env}" == "syst")`

Comment: ohh yeah, its working, i had something else failing , '==' is perfectly working.