# To find a string from a list is not working as expected using contains

Tags: groovy

I have a list which is defined as below:

```
def list1=["Test1","Test2","Test3"]
String str="Test2"

println("Found The String is:"+list1.contains(str));

//It is returning false even though there is a matching string.
```

Comment: This example is not failing for me (Groovy 2.5.6)

Comment: Works for me too (Groovy 2.4.8, JVM 1.8.0_201 [not sure if jvm has anything to do with it])

Answer (score 0):

What you've typed in there does work, so there's something else wrong.  My guess is that you've done something like:

```
String part = "Test"
String str="Test2"
def list1=["${part}1","${part}2","Test3"]
def found = list1.contains(str)
```

in this case, `found` will be false... because:

`"${'test'}"` is *not* equal to `"test"`, for some definitions of equal... even though printing them both makes you think so.

Here's why: [Groovy different results on using equals() and == on a GStringImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682206/groovy-different-results-on-using-equals-and-on-a-gstringimpl)