# Groovy: GString is not found in the String collection

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to extract a part of the string and check whether it exists in the array of strings. If I use string interpolation(or GStrings), it's giving weird result.

```
def str = "app-dev"

def env = str.split('-')[1]
println(env + " length: " + env.length()) // prints dev length: 3
println(env in ['dev', 'qa']) // prints true, works as expected.

def _env = "${str.split('-')[1]}" // string interpolation or GString
println(_env + " length: " + _env.length()) // prints dev length: 3
println(_env in ['dev', 'qa']) // prints false, why ?
println(_env.trim() in ['dev', 'qa']) // prints true :|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the string length, actually. Without trimming, this will produce `true`:

```
println(_env.toString() in ['dev', 'qa']) // prints true :|
```

The problem is that `in` operator uses `equals` for comparison and `equals` of `GString` doesn't work as you may expect it. Add these lines to your code:

```
println _env == 'dev'
println _env.equals('dev')
```

It will produce:

```
true
false
```

Why it is so? I do not know, but I like the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9682610/1842599) I quote:

> Obviously the GStringImpl implementation of equals could have been written such that when it is passed a String that contain the same characters as this, it returns true. I'm guessing that the reason it wasn't written this way is because it would violate the equals contract, which states that:

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y)
> should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

> The implementation of String.equals(Object other) will always return false when passed a GSStringImpl, so if GStringImpl.equals(Object other) returns true when passed any String, it would be in violation of the symmetric requirement.

Checkout the whole discussion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682206/groovy-different-results-on-using-equals-and-on-a-gstringimpl). I hope it will help you to understand what is going on.

Comment: trim() actually does nothing in this case, because there are no spaces, but it has a side effect, that is convering the result to a string. It's effect is the same as toString().

Comment: @Catalin absolutely